# JAVA Utility/Plugin to find XML difference

Tags: xml, xmldiff

I am looking for an utility/plugin in java to find difference between two XML files efficiently. Can you please provide a few suggestions to choose the best one?

Thanks in Advance.

Regards
Kishore

Answer (score 0):

There's [XMLUnit](http://www.xmlunit.org/), which is a library designed to be used alongside JUnit or TestNG and which provides XML diff. I've used v1.1 and it did a good job. I see they have v2.0 now, but I have no experience with it.

Comment: Thanks Ivant..Can we run XMLUnit from a standAlone java class?

Comment: Yes. Specifically it has a Diff class, which you can use for comparison.